# How to save ManyToMany field in Django?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have models like this:

```
class GuestStatus(models.Model):
    guest_status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    arrangement = models.IntegerField(unique=True, help_text="Start from 1. Guest status will be arranged alphabetically.")


class Guest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    status = models.ManyToManyField(GuestStatus, blank=True, null=True)
    invitation_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want `ManyToManyField` to be shown as checkbox. That's why I am doing like this:

```
class GuestForm(ModelForm):
    status = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=GuestStatus.objects.all().order_by('arrangement'), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Guest
        exclude = ['user', 'invitation_date']
```

I am trying to save form like this:

```
    form = GuestForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        status = form.cleaned_data['status']
        guest.status = status
        if status:
            invitation_date = datetime.now() 
        else:
            invitation_date = None
        new_guest = form.save(commit=False)

        new_guest.user = request.user
        new_guest.save()
        new_guest.status = status
        form.save_m2m()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/list_guests/')
```

The form is saving all the data but not `status` value. What is wrong? Also, after successfully saving how can I access the status value in template? Thanks

Comment: Because you have `new_guest.status = status` after you've saved the `new_guest`

Comment: If I write `new_guest.status=status` after `new_guest.user = request.user` and later do `new_guest.save()` I get this error: `<Guest: guesteeu>" needs to have a value for field "guest" before this many-to-many relationship can be used`

Comment: If the form has `status` field, you don't need to set it explicitly as `new_guest.status=status`, rather just do `form.save_m2m()`.

Comment: Did. Still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
form = GuestForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    if status:
        invitation_date = datetime.now() 
    else:
        invitation_date = None

    new_guest = form.save(commit=False)
    new_guest.user = request.user
    new_guest.save()

    status = form.cleaned_data['status']
    for stat in status:
        new_guest.status_set.create(guest_status = stat['guest_status'], arrangement = stat['arrangement'])

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/list_guests/')
```

After you get your `new_guest` instance you create `GuestStatus` instances and bind them to `new_guest`.

Or if `GuestStatus` is your dictionary you can :

```
    for stat in status:
        gs = GuestStatus.objects.get(pk = stat['guest_status'])
        new_guest.status_set.add(gs)
```

Hope you understood me and my english :)

Comment: `'Guest' object has no attribute 'status_set'` error while saving!

Comment: What django version ur using? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/relations/